# How and where can we request new WordPress hooks to be added?

Tags: hooks, automatic-updates

I use the great Changelogger plugin, which adds plugin version history to the plugins page when there is an update. Although I would like it to, it doesn't work from the updates page where you can update WordPress core, plugins, and themes.

How and where can a new hook for that page be requested so that the changelogs can be added to that page too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to make a new ticket here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/

Explain why you want a new hook and how it could be used. Including a patch file also goes a long ways towards getting the hook included in WordPress.

Answer (score 6):

Things will move the quickest if you're willing to do some work on your own.

1. Take some time to write a patch with your proposed hook
2. Post a ticket on the [WordPress Trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/) explaining the hook, why it's important, and linking to your patch file.
3. Send a message to [WP-Hackers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Mailing_Lists#Hackers) explaining the same and referencing your Trac ticket.
4. Attend the WP development chat on IRC on Thursday - bring the ticket up there as well and ask a core contributer to take a look at it.

If your reasoning is well thought-out you might not need to do all 4 ... but just asking for a patch won't get you anywhere unless you're willing (or know someone who is) to write it.  Mentioning it in these three places (Trac, WP-Hackers, IRC) is the best way to involve a core developer and either get it committed to core or get the feedback you need to build a new patch.

Comment: Just as a follow up, I finally got around to posting a ticket and creating a patch, which will be included in 3.3  -  http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17451

Answer (score 1):

I would send a message to [wp-hackers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Mailing_Lists#Hackers), or create a ticket and submit a patch on the [WordPress trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/).